# how to cout a subclass after static cast into a vector

Tags: c++

I have two classes, `Article` and a subclass `ArticleOnSale` (public inheritance).

And also a class `Boutique`, which contains a `vector<Article*> arts`.

I have defined the `<<` operator for both `Article` and `ArticleOnSale`

In `Articles.cpp` I have a public `Addarticle`

```cpp
void Addarticle(Article* a)
{
    Article* p;
    if (typeid(*a) == typeid(Article))
    {
        p = new Article(a);
        arts.push_back(p);
        cout << "\narticle\n";
    }
    else
    {
        p = new ArticleEnSolde(static_cast<const ArticleEnSolde&>(*arts[arts.size()])); //creates a huge problem 
        arts.push_back(p);
    }
}
```

When I want to print out the articles, it only uses the `<<` of `Article` for both `Article` and `ArticleOnSale`.

```cpp
ostream & operator<<(ostream& n, Boutique a)
{
    n<<"\nshowing boutique:\n";
    Article* p;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.arts.size(); i++)
    {
        p = a.arts[i];
        if (typeid(*a.arts[i]) == typeid(Article))
        { 
            n << *a.arts[i];
            n << "\narticle not on sale detected\n";
        }
        else 
        {
            n << "i can detect article on sale";//just debugging (doesn't work)
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: You are missing some fundamental concepts of how C++ works. Your `a` parameter will ***always*** be an `Article`, so comparing to a `typeid` of an `Article` will ***always*** be true. Furthermore, there are very few reasons in C++ to resort to using `typeid` in the first place. There's rarely a valid reason to do so. Do you [have a good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) where you can learn more about how to correctly pass parameters to functions, and using inheritance?

Comment: thank you for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible implementation that takes better advantage of virtual functions would be something like this:

```
class Article {
public:
    virtual bool is_on_sale() const { return false; }
};

class ArticleOnSale {
public:
    virtual bool is_on_sale() const { return true; }
};
```

then your vector would need to look like:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Article>> arts;

// add an Article:
arts.push_back(std::make_unique<Article>());

// or on sale
arts.push_back(std::make_unique<ArticleOnSale>());
```

(the `unique_ptr` is needed so that the C++ virtual functions will behave, without the pointer-ness of it this wouldn't work).

Finally, the ostream operator becomes fairly concise:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream& os,Boutique a ) {
    for (auto& ptr : a.arts) {
        os << (ptr->is_on_sale() ? "article on sale " : "article is full price ")
    }
}
```

Of course there may be better ways of going about, like maybe just storing a boolean variable inside the `Article` if it's on sale - but I hope that makes the code behave more like you were expecting!

Comment: `const Boutique& a` would be better for the function parameter. No reason to make a copy just to print it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous problems with this code.

In `Addarticle()`, `typeid(*a)` will always be equal to `typeid(Article)`.  The correct way to check if `a` is pointing at an object of a particular derived type is to use `dynamic_cast` instead, eg:

```cpp
if (dynamic_cast<ArticleEnSolde*>(a))
{
    // a is an ArticleEnSolde ...
}
else
{
    // a is not an ArticleEnSolde ...
}
```

Also, in `static_cast<const ArticleEnSolde&>(*arts[arts.size()])`, accessing `arts[arts.size()]` is going out of bounds of the `vector`.  You likely meant to cast `a` instead.

However, in this situation, you should use the `clone()` idiom instead, if you are not going to push `a` itself as-is into the `vector`:

```cpp
class Article
{
public:
    virtual Article* clone() const;
};

class ArticleEnSolde : public Article
{
public:
    Article* clone() const override;
};

...

Article* Article::clone() const
{
    return new Article(*this);
}

Article* ArticleEnSolde::clone() const
{
    return new ArticleEnSolde(*this);
}

void Addarticle(Article* a)
{
    Article* p = a->clone();
    arts.push_back(p);
}
```

Regarding printing, you are invoking `operator<<` only for `Article` because that is the type of object you are passing to it. It has no way to know whether the object is actually an `ArticleEnSolde` or not. For polymorphic types, you should instead define a `virtual` method in the base class, and then define `operator<<` for that class and have it call the virtual method:

```cpp
class Article
{
public:
    virtual void print(ostream &n) const;
};

class ArticleEnSolde : public Article
{
public:
    void print(ostream &n) const override;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& n, const Article &a);

...

void Article::print(ostream &n) const
{
    n << "\narticle not on sale\n";
}

void ArticleEnSolde::print(ostream &n) const
{
    n << "\narticle on sale\n";
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& n, const Article &a)
{
    a.print(n);
    return n;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& n, const Boutique &a)
{
    n << "\nshowing boutique:\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.arts.size(); ++i)
    {
        n << *(a.arts[i]);
    }
    return n;
}
```